# How to download the latest file from a FTP location

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013

How to download the latest file from a FTP location? I have lots of files in a FTP location, someone today placed 3 files in ftp location. I want to download three latest files using c#.net.

Comment: Can you show your attempts so far?

Answer (score -1):

try below;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public static int DownloadFtp(string filePath, string fileName, string ftpServerIP, string ftpUserID, string ftpPassword)
{
    FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
    try
    {
        //filePath = < <The full path where the file is to be created.>>, 
        //fileName = < <Name of the file to be created(Need not be the name of the file on FTP server).>> 
        FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(filePath + "\\" + fileName, FileMode.Create);

        reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + fileName));
        reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
        reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
        reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
        Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        long cl = response.ContentLength;
        int bufferSize = 2048;
        int readCount;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        while (readCount > 0)
        {
            outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
            readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        ftpStream.Close();
        outputStream.Close();
        response.Close();
        return 0;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Logging.WriteError(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
        // System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return -2;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this downlolad "the latest files"? (I assume OP wants the latest files uploaded on the FTP location)